# Getting info from child pages from masterpage codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my site, I have a set of 5 user settings pages. They each use a master page called `settings.master`. In the codebehind, the class definition for the pages looks like this:

```
public partial class AccountSettings : PageEx
```

The class definition for the master page looks like this:

```
public partial class Settings : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
```

`PageEx` has an object called `LoggedInUserInfo`. This is populated during `OnInit` with all the information about the logged in user.

I want to access the object `LoggedInUserInfo` from the master page. So, on the master page, I want to refer to an object owned by the child page. Is this possible?

Comment: Am I the only one who would expect that the **Masterpage** contains the LoggedInUserInfo and the detail can use it?

Comment: @Pleun On my site, not all `PageEx` pages also have the masterpage `settings.master`. However, not all pages belonging to the general, site-wide master page inherit for `PageEx`.

Comment: Well, too me it seems for all your pages the LoggedInUSerInfo is usefull. Did you know you can have NESTED master pages? This seems something you can put in the overall master page and inherit subsequent (sub)master pages from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure is

in the master

```
(Page as PageEx).LoggedInUserInfo.Somefunction();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great, though I didn't expect it to. Clearly I don't know enough about how master pages work.

Comment: @sll There are two. Does this make a difference?

Comment: And you need access LoggedInUserInfo of the each of them? INteresting what you will get in this.Page of master page in case of two content placeholders, can you check it?

Answer (score 2):

`LoggedInUserInfo` sounds like something that should be in the [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx). Perhaps you could retrieve it from the session state in the Master Page.

You can put the code that populates the object in the `Session_Start` event of `Global.asax`. This way it will only be invoked once per user that logs in.

Comment: The object contains all the data about the user - large bodies of profile description text, the URLs of variable numbers of images, addresses, phone numbers and emails, so I decided to bring it up only when needed, rather than putting it all in Session.

Answer (score 2):

For each which is page rendered in scope of a given Master page single field of type [ContentPlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder.aspx) has been generated. (See `MasterPage.designer.cs`). By accessing [ContentPlaceHolder.Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx) property and casting to the underlying page type you would be able access what you need:

```
// MainContent - name of your content place holder for a specific page rendered
// in scope of Master page
(this.MainContent.Page as PageEx).LoggedInUserInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You'll just need to put the LoggedInUserInfo somewhere accessible to the MasterPage (HttpContext.Items, HttpContext.Session etc), however the fact that you do need to access this information from the MasterPage suggests that it should be a property of the MasterPage, which is far more easily referenced from the child pages.